# Restrict File Dialog for a particular Location

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I want to use a OpenFileDialog with Initial Folder "C:\MyFiles" and I also want to make restriction that user cannot navigate out of this location. Means User can only access the location "C:\MyFiles". Is there any property or method for achieve this task.

Comment: In short, you cannot do this witth the standard `OpenFileDialog`, and you probably shouldn't consider doing it anyway.